# Python progressbar2- Display filename under progressbar

Tags: python, progress-bar

I'm using progressbar2 library in order to display a progressbar of files download.

I would like to print out the name of the currently downloaded file in the line under (or above) the progressbar line and have each file name printed on the same line.

```
import progressbar

format_custom_text = progressbar.FormatCustomText(
    'Downloading file:%(f)s',
    dict(
        f='',
    ),
)

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[
    progressbar.Counter(format='[%(value)02d/%(max_value)d]'),
    progressbar.Bar(marker=u'\u2588', fill='.', left='|', right='|'),
    format_custom_text])

for i in bar(range(len(files))):
    format_custom_text.update_mapping(f=files[i])
    client.download_file(file_path=files[i])
```

Example:

```
[25/64] |███████████████████████............................| Downloading file: dummyfile.txt
```

What I want is to change the name of the file and still print it on the same line under the progressbar.

```
[25/64] |███████████████████████............................| 

Downloading file: dummyfile.txt
```

Comment: Can't you just pass the desired file name to `update_mapping()` ?

Comment: the output now is everything on the same line. I want to find a way to display the file name under the progressbar. I edited the question so it will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, on the terminal:

```
import time
import progressbar

format_custom_text = progressbar.FormatCustomText(
    '\nDownloading file:%(f)s\033[F',
    dict(
        f='',
    ),
)

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[
    progressbar.Counter(format='[%(value)02d/%(max_value)d]'),
    progressbar.Bar(marker=u'\u2588', fill='.', left='|', right='|'),
    format_custom_text])
files=list(range(1000))
for i in bar(range(len(files))):
    format_custom_text.update_mapping(f=files[i])
    time.sleep(0.1)
```